# Serial port access error in WINE

Tags: serial-port, wine

I have a setup in which i use a USB serial adapter + some applicationwhich sends and receives data using that serial usb. But this setup which works on a Windows, or even in a VMWare Virtual windows, does not work under WINE. IT transmits data but i cannot receive data. The cable and the applications are same as in the working and non-working scenarios. I guess The fact that the application works over the USB serial cable just as fine under Virtual Windows(VMware running on linux) by mapping /dev/ttyUSB to the com port, no external software/DLL needed, means it does not need any specific driver. (Am i correct in this assumption that application doesnt need any driver?)

(I also tried with a different setup(different USB serial adapter + different application under WINE, but even that does not work under WINE, but it works fine under WIndows/Virtual Windows)

How can i get it working under WINE?

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Never tried wine with a serial port, but this could help:

```
cd .wine/dosdevices
ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0 com1
```

Comment: @goldenmean, you need to add yourself to `dialout` group and re-login. Do this by running `sudo adduser <you_login> dialout`.